# update multiple rows of one column by single submit button : AngularJS with PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to update a column (FraisFact) of several lines, each line to an identifier (CodeCompleteColumn), how I can do this with angularJS and PHP knowing that I managed to display the inofrmation of each code by ( Ng-repeat) and I can not predict the number of codes displayed and I have to update "FraisFact" of each "CodeEnvoiColis"
fichier.html

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="x in namesF3 " >
          <div class="item item-divider center-text" name="codeE" ng-model="codeE" value={{x.CodeEnvoiColis}} > {{x.CodeEnvoiColis}} </div>

          <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Frais" name="frais" ng-model="frais"></div> 
          </label> 
</ion-list>    
      <a class="button button-info" href="#/factureAdmin" ng-
      click=updateFactFact(x.frais)> Ajouter </a>
```

app.js :

```
 $scope.insertFact = function(frais){  
           $http.post(  
                "http://localhost/deb/updateFact.php",  
                {           
                'frais':$scope.frais,
                'codeE':$scope.codeE,
                 }
           ).success(function(data){  
                alert(data);    
                $scope.frais=null;
                $scope.codeE=null;        
           });  
    }
```

updateFact.php

```
 <?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sem1");   
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));   
   if(count($data) > 0)  
 {  
      $FraisFact = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->frais);       
      $CodeEnvoiColis = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->codeE);  
    $query = "UPDATE colis 
    SET 
    FraisFact='.$FraisFact.'
    WHERE CodeEnvoiColis='.$CodeEnvoiColis'";     
  }  
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "epmsxs"); 

    $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $tot = count($postdata); 
    //echo json_encode($postdata);
    for($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++) {
    $FraisFact = $postdata[$i]->frais;
    $CodeEnvoiColis = $postdata[$i]->codeE;

    //u can use echo for alert response.data
    echo $FraisFact;
    echo $CodeEnvoiColis ;
    mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE colis 
    SET 
    FraisFact=$FraisFact
    WHERE CodeEnvoiColis=$CodeEnvoiColis");
    }

?>
```

Comment: it's better if you pass some text explain this answer

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining what i tried to do there.

Comment: it's never to late to improve it, just hit the [edit] button

Answer (score 0):

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

this snippet takes the data from the external page and merges with the PHP page.

```
$tot = count($postdata);
```

It counts the number of rows in the arriving data through `$http.post`

then applying a for loop as shown above.

It will insert the data based on the count of data coming through post method
for example(if no:of rows are 3 that is $tot is three then the query will be executed 3 times each time taking `$CodeEnvoiColis`'s value as the parameter for WHERE clause).

I hope it is clear. Please let me know if I am missing something